# How to create custom encoding of Option types with Circe?

Tags: scala, circe

It's possible to have a class that looks like so:

```
case class Amount(value: Int)
case class Data(insurance: Option[Amount], itemPrice: Amount)
```

If `insurance = None` it should get a default value of `waived: true`

E.g:

```
Data(Some(123),100).asJson

// output
{
  "insurance": {
    "value": 123
  },
  "price": 100
}

And when no Insurance is opted for:

Data(None,100).asJson

// output
{
  "insurance": {
    "waived: true
  },
  "price": 100
}
```

How can this fine-grained control be achieved? I tried various tricks with `forProduct2` and `mapJsonObject` but couldn't get it to behave right:

```
implicit val testEncoder = deriveEncoder[Option[Amount]].mapJsonObject(j => {

    val x = j("Some") match {
      case Some(s) => // need to convert to [amount -> "value"]
      case None => JsonObject.apply(("waived",Json.fromBoolean(true)))
    }

    x
  })
```

This can easily get me the `waived:true` part but no idea how to handle the `Some(s)` case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If having `{"waived": true}` is expected behavior for any `Option[Amount]` if it's None, then you can rely on semiauto derived encoders if you write your custom encoder for `Option[Amount]`

Here is an example

```scala
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

case class Amount(value: Int)
case class Data(insurance: Option[Amount], itemPrice: Amount)

object Amount {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Amount] = deriveEncoder
}

object Data {
  implicit val encoderOptionalAmount: Encoder[Option[Amount]] = (optA: Option[Amount]) =>
      optA match {
        case Some(amount) => amount.asJson
        case None => Json.obj("waived" -> true.asJson)
      }

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Data] = deriveEncoder[Data]
}

println(Data(insurance = None, itemPrice = Amount(10)).asJson)

/*
{
  "insurance" : {
    "waived" : true
  },
  "itemPrice" : {
    "value" : 10
  }
}
*/
```

How it works: `deriveEncoder[Data]` will call implicit encoders for both itemPrice (of type `Amount`) and insurance of type `Option[Amount]`.

Default encoder for `Option[T]` just skips the value if it's `None` but since we defined another implicit encoder for `Option[T]` in the closest scope (Data object-companion) it won't look for implicit encoders in global scopes giving you exactly what you want.

Comment: This is an interesting pattern. Lemme try it. May help with “other” questions too :)

Comment: If having an encoder for Option[Amount] is not an option for you (no pun intended), let me know. I have another solution

Comment: I’d still add it though. It may help with the case of “what if” at some place we just want Option.None